# Ada: Convert an access to constant to access to variable

Tags: pointers, constants, ada

What is the proper way to convert an access to constant to access to 
variable? (Yes, I know that then I need to be careful not to modify this 
"variable".)

Maybe `Unchecked_Conversion`?

But:

1. Is `Unchecked_Conversion` guaranteed by the standard to work well in this 
   case?
2. Is there a simpler way than `Unchecked_Conversion`?

Answer (score 3):

`Unchecked_Conversion` is not guaranteed to work in that case, as Ada doesn't give you any guarantees about the memory layout of access types.  Supposedly Ada intentionally allows the compiler to have unique memory layouts and meanings for each access type.

If you add a `Convention => C` aspect to your access types, you may get the common memory layout you want, as C considers all pointers to operate on the same address space.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, what's going on is [likely] that there's a mismatch in parameter modes (and maybe type-definitions) somewhere.

Let's say there's a few types:

```
Type Window(<>) is tagged private;
Type Constant_Reference is not null constant access Window'Class;
Type Reference is not null access Window'Class;
Type Handle is access Window'Class;
```

Given `Function Get_Handle ( Object : in out aliased Window'Class )` what can we say about `Object'Access`? Well, it's an access to Window'Class which is not constant -- so it is compatible with both `Handle` and `Reference` but not `Constant_Reference`.

On the other hand, if we had `Function Get_Handle ( Object : aliased Window'Class )` then `Object'Access` would yield an anonymous access which is compatible with `Constant_Reference` due to the constant nature of the in-parameter.

So, check your parameters and your design, and see if that's what's causing your issues.